# Extracting queries from log file that do not include banned lines

Tags: shell, shell-script

I have a log file that looks something like the following:

```
query1 startQuery
query1 do something
query1 do something else
query2 startQuery
query1 do something banned
query2 do something
query3 startQuery
query2 endQuery 1000
query3 something else to do
query1 endQuery 2003
query3 do something
query4 startQuery
query4 endQuery 100
query3 endQuery 1434
```

I am finding the longest running queries:

```
> grep "endQuery" logfile | awk '{print $3 " " $1}' | sort -nr | head -n 3
2003 query1
1434 query3
1000 query2
```

However, there are certain operations known to be long, and I want to find the longest running queries that *do not* include these operations. For example, I want to find the longest running queries that do not, in any of their log lines, include the word "banned".

In this example it would output:

```
1434 query3
1000 query2
100 query4
```

In reality these log files are large and contain a lot of queries.

Comment: Advice: don't use the shell for that, use some programming language ;-) Would you accept answers in C, python, whatever…?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that you don't need the call to `grep`, by the way: it can be seamlessly integrated into the `awk` call.

```
<logfile awk '/endQuery/ {print $3 " " $1}'
```

You can filter out the banned queries at the awk stage. Store ongoing queries in an array, remove them if they're banned, and only print out the non-banned ones.

```
<logfile awk '
    $2 == "startQuery" {q[$1]=1}        # store the names of active queries
    q[$1] && /banned/ {delete q[$1]}    # delete banned queries
    $2 == "endQuery" {
        if (q[$1]) print $3, $1;        # only report non-banned queries
        delete q[$1];
    }
' | sort -nr | head -n 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to formulate the following:

```
diff <(grep "endQuery" logfile | awk '{print $1}') \
     <(grep "banned"   logfile | awk '{print $1}') | \
  grep "<" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{0} grep "{0} endQuery" logfile | \
    awk '{print $3 " " $1}' | sort -nr | head -n3
1434 query3
1000 query2
100 query4
```

However, it requires grepping through the log file 3 times, which can be expensive for large log files.