# Searching a file & excluding lines with a specified string

Tags: shell, command-line, command

I have a large log file that contains numerous lines of the same entry, lets call it "repeat-info". As an example here is what a portion of the log might look like:

```
[Timestamp] repeat-info
[Timestamp] repeat-info
[Timestamp] Log information 1
[Timestamp] Log information 2
[Timestamp] repeat-info
[Timestamp] Log information 3
[Timestamp] repeat-info
```

Is there a command that can output the information in the log file and exclude the repeated information?  It becomes a hassle if I have to use `more file.log` and sift through all the repeating information to find what it is I want to look at.

I am reading through the man pages for `sed` and `awk` as I saw those appear in searches for my question, however I haven't found anything conclusive that would do what I need.

I was searching through the older questions and found [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20024/extracting-queries-from-log-file-that-do-not-include-banned-lines)  which is related to mine.

I was looking for a way to do this with a single command, or two piped together, without having to create a script.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Is it just a simple `grep -v` or is it something more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Best would be `grep`:

```
grep -v 'repeat-info' file.log
```

Other ways:

```
sed '/repeat-info/d' file.log
sed -n '/repeat-info/!p' file.log

awk '!/repeat-info/' file.log
```

Comment: I would add `perl -ni -e 'print unless /repeat-info/' file.log`

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for the help!  I was not aware one of the options for `grep` was to inverse the command.

Comment: @Kevin Is there a way to use this same thing and exclude two different lines of information? (Eg. exclude two sets of repeated information from the same log file. Such as `grep -v 'repeat-info' && 'more-repeated-info' file.log`).

Comment: @SirCobalt yes, you can use `-e` to specify more than one pattern, e.g. `grep -v -e 'repeat-info' -e 'more-repeat' file.log`